# pyagentx snmp, how is the code linked to the MIB?

Tags: python, snmp

I am looking at pyagentx (extending snmp agents) through python. https://github.com/rayed/pyagentx

I don't follow how the example code is linked to the MIB. Example here would be `class NetSnmpTestMibTable` being linked to `netSnmpIETFWGTable` from `NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt` http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
Rayed Alrashed 2015-06-14
AgentX sub agent that implement some parts of NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB:
<http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt>
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleScalars
snmptable -v 2c -c public -Ci localhost NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpIETFWGTable 
Try snmpset:
snmpset -v 2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleInteger.0 i 10
snmpset -v 2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleInteger.0 i 200
snmpset -v 2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleString.0 s "Test"
'''

import time
import random
import pyagentx

def str_to_oid(data):
    length = len(data)
    oid_int = [str(ord(i)) for i in data]
    return str(length) + '.' + '.'.join(oid_int)


class NetSnmpTestMibScalar(pyagentx.Updater):

    def update(self):
        self.set_INTEGER('1.0', 1000)
        self.set_OCTETSTRING('3.0', 'String for NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB')
        self.set_OBJECTIDENTIFIER('4.0', '1.2')
        self.set_IPADDRESS('5.0', '127.0.0.1')
        self.set_COUNTER32('6.0', 2000)
        self.set_GAUGE32('7.0', 2000)
        self.set_TIMETICKS('8.0', 1000000)
        self.set_OPAQUE('9.0', 'Test')
        self.set_COUNTER64('10.0', 2000)


class NetSnmpTestMibTable(pyagentx.Updater):

    def update(self):
        # implement netSnmpIETFWGTable from NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
        # Number of entries in table is random to show that MIB is reset
        # on every update
        for i in range(random.randint(3, 5)):
            idx = str_to_oid('group%s' % (i+1))
            self.set_OCTETSTRING('1.1.2.' + idx, 'member 1')
            self.set_OCTETSTRING('1.1.3.' + idx, 'member 2')


class NetSnmpIntegerSet(pyagentx.SetHandler):

    def test(self, oid, data):
        if int(data) > 100:
            raise pyagentx.SetHandlerError()

    def commit(self, oid, data):
        print "COMMIT CALLED: %s = %s" % (oid, data)


class MyAgent(pyagentx.Agent):

    def setup(self):
        self.register('1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.1', NetSnmpTestMibScalar)
        self.register('1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.2', NetSnmpTestMibTable)
        self.register_set('1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.1.1.0', NetSnmpIntegerSet)


def main():
    pyagentx.setup_logging()
    try:
        a = MyAgent()
        a.start()
    except Exception as e:
        print "Unhandled exception:", e
        a.stop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        a.stop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

If I run a command I get the output as expected but I am unsure of how it is working, how does the code know to update`netSnmpIETFWGTable` ?
As you can see i can read the values from it set by this example code:

```
snmptable -v 2c -c public -Ci localhost NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpIETFWGTable 
SNMP table: NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpIETFWGTable

   index nsIETFWGChair1 nsIETFWGChair2
"group1"     "member 1"     "member 2"
"group2"     "member 1"     "member 2"
"group3"     "member 1"     "member 2"
```

Comment: I never received any feedback regarding the answer I left; did it solve your problem? If it did, marking it as accepted would be appreciated; thanks.

Comment: @miken32 I was in an accident after I wrote this and haven't used a computer in months until today - due to broken bones, I will check out your answer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object names in the [MIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base) are like a DNS entry, they're just pointing to [an ugly number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier) in the background.

Looking in [`NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB`](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt) you can see `netSnmpIETFWGTable` defined as `netSnmpExamples 2`. Scrolling up a couple of lines shows `netSnmpExamples` defined as `netSnmp 2`. This is declared in the `IMPORTS` section as coming from [`NET-SNMP-MIB`](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt), so you'd need to look there to see what `netSnmp` is, etc. The [`SNMPv2-SMI`](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.txt) MIB is the top of the chain for SNMP.

What you end up with is that `netSnmpIETFWGTable` translates to `1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.2.1`. Looking down to the initialization code at the bottom of your file, you can see the parent of this OID being linked to the class:

```
self.register('1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.2', NetSnmpTestMibTable)
```

Which should hopefully answer your question, "how does the code know to update `netSnmpIETFWGTable`."

---

You can also try out the `snmptranslate` utility, which is easier than looking through MIB files!

```
$ snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpIETFWGTable
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.2.1
$ snmptranslate -Of NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpIETFWGTable
.iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.netSnmp.netSnmpExamples.netSnmpExampleTables.netSnmpIETFWGTable
$ snmptranslate 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.2.1
NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpIETFWGTable
$ snmptranslate -Of 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.2.1
.iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.netSnmp.netSnmpExamples.netSnmpExampleTables.netSnmpIETFWGTable
```

Comment: So i get to the import of NET-SNMP-MIB http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt This is the part I don't get, where does it show it is translated as 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.2.1? Is there a further step? Thanks for the help! That translate tool is handy

Comment: When the MIB says `IMPORTS netSnmp FROM NET-SNMP-MIB` that means it's pulling from another MIB. So you can see inside that MIB that `netSnmp` is defined as `enterprises 8072`, which is imported from `SNMPv2-SMI`...